# How to replace all characters contain uppercase and lowercase letters to only uppercase letters in pentaho using regex?

Tags: regex, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to replace uppercase lowercase letters with corresponding uppercase letters using regex in pentaho with replace in string. Example

```
Apple
apple
APPLE
```

expected result

```
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
```

How can I uppercase all letters only in words that contain both lower and uppercase letters?

What should i write in here?
[replace in string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G1Hx.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the Calculator step with the Calculation "UpperCase of a string A"

Comment: yes i can use other step but for this i need to use replace in string step only